# scp stalls and ssh sessions freeze up (but eventually start again)

Tags: ssh, scp

I am running ubuntu on various computers on a home wireless network. Some are on 9.04x64, some 10.04x64 and one 9.04x32.

Running `scp` with a large file starts out at 2.1 mbps and drops down to about 200k, stalling and dropping until the transfer is complete. I've noticed this when I have a secure shell open on any of these servers as well.

I have tried this with 2 different routers, both brand new, different brands.

Comment: I would look into using rsync for transfering large files. Especially if you do this frequently. If rsync dies, mid transfer, when you run it again, it won't copy /all/ of the data again. It will fix amy corruption on the receiving end, and start where it stopped.

Comment: yeah, rsync is unbelievably slow too - i'm running:

rsync -azvv -e ssh charles@192.168.1.140:./bigfile.tar.gz .

Comment: Don't forget to pass `--partial` to rsync, or it will delete any partially-transferred large files when the connection dies.

Comment: What's the packet loss like between the two machines?

What's the packet loss like when you use bigger packets (`sudo ping -s 2000 otherhost`)?

Comment: using the -z option when you're transferring .gz files will be pointless.  You're not likely to notice the overhead, but your system will try to recompress it again on the fly.  Not relevant to your current issue, just putting that out there.

Comment: Is there a process running on any of these machines that may impact disk write speed? Or cpu performance? Scp-ing files is not *just* about the network, as compressing/encrypting takse CPU grunt, and the data has to be read from and written to spinning disks usually, so there's more potential bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a transfer between two of the systems while they were directly connected to each other? That's the only sure-fire way to rule out the network gear as a source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect wifi issues, but that can be ruled out by just connecting them together via ethernet (either through a switch or cross-over cable).